# onTouchListener in RecyclerView in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, ontouchlistener

i'm using RecyclerView inside of SwipeRefreshLayout which is inside of ViewPager... it happened that i need to detect 2 tap events on each item, so i set onTouchListener like:

```
holder.itemView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            GestureListener gestureListener = new GestureListener(...);
            GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, gestureListener);
            gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

GestureListener class itself is:

```
private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    GestureListener(...) {
        // Handle data
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "1 tap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "2 tap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

but those above does not work... i tried focusable="true" then "false" then clickable="true" and false, but none of it works.... i don't know if the problem is that recycle view itself is located in so many touch related views... so how can i make double tap work?

Comment: When you use `return true;` on a touch event you prevent future callbacks related to the same touch event (like ON_DRAG).. use `return false;` in the `onTouch()` callback.

Comment: did not help, well, swipe refresh and view pager works perfectly, just onSingleTap and onDoubleTab is the problem.... it does not detect any of tap

Comment: Oh I see.. For every touch you create a new instances of the 'GestureHelpers'. So you need to initialise them once, outside of the onTouch scope, and pass the event to the same instance..

Comment: A few questions: 1) How are you planning to detect which item was clicked? 2) Does `onTouch` ever get's called? || (You should still return false in every callback if detecting touches is all you want to do)

Comment: Yep, it is working, just had to init once and remove previously changed return values from false to true and it worked, it's slower then onClick tho, but no other ways :D thanks, for detecting item i'm passing position then getting item from Array

Comment: Happy to hear :) good luck!